# parsing of xml attributes with references using DOM parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing

**I am having problem parsing  xml attribute (Mon,tue and others like them) in the below xml**

```
>    <Root>
>     <Details Timing="09-10 AM"  Mon="Lecture/G:All&#xD;C:MTH402/R:33-608&#xD;S:K1305"
> Tue="Lecture/G:All&#xD;C:ECO310/R:33-608&#xD;S:K1305"
> Thu="Practical/G:2&#xD;C:CSE427/R:34-304&#xD;S:K1305"
> Sat="Lecture/G:All&#xD;C:ELQ171/R:33-501&#xD;S:K10G2" />
>     </Root>
```

//code to generate logs but only time is displayed in logs

```
 protected void porcesssxml(File file)
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder=documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument=documentBuilder.parse(file);
            Element rootElement= xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodeList1=rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Details");
            Node currenttag=null;

            for(int i=0;i<nodeList1.getLength();i++)
            {   currenttag =nodeList1.item(i);
                Log.d("test",currenttag.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());//display timing
                Log.d("test",currenttag.getAttributes().item(1).getTextContent()); //display mon 

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is merely a statement. If you want help, you should phrase your question to specifically say what you want. Please also post any attempt you have already made so afr! You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Comment: Do you get an error message? What language are you using to parse the attributes? How are you parsing them? Try and edit your post and add these pieces of information then you are more likely to receive an answer

Comment: i am using DOM parser in android to parse this xml

Comment: how can i get the text  stored in mon,tue,thu and others